# primary and foreign keys in postgresql - total beginner

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, primary-key

can anyone explain me how to connect these tables?
I have to be able to list population in a country, list population in a city and list number of employees in a company for each city it is present in! The only limitation is that city name is unique and company can be present only once in one city but can have many branches in one country.

I have made country, company and city tables but I cannot understand how to connect them properly and get this functionality. I watched some youtube tutorials and read many posts but I still can't seem to make it work. If someone can help I would appreciate it. Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Please add the table definitions (`CREATE TABLE (...)`) that you have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One entity that is missing from your list is `branch` (of the company). The table definitions are then:

```
CREATE TABLE country (
  id         integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name       varchar NOT NULL,
  population integer NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE city (
  id         integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name       varchar NOT NULL,
  population integer NOT NULL,
  country    integer NOT NULL REFERENCES country(id)
);
```

Simple. You have a list of countries and a list of cities. The city records have a column `country` that references the proper record in the `country` table. City name is not set `UNIQUE` here because different countries can have a city by the same name (English, Dutch, Portuguese and Spanish empires created new cities with old names which were sometimes distinguishable (New York) but not always (such as Melbourne)). Append the `UNIQUE` clause to the `name` column if you really want the city name to be unique.

```
CREATE TABLE company (
  id         integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name       varchar NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE branch (
  company    integer NOT NULL REFERENCES company(id),
  city       integer NOT NULL REFERENCES city(id),
  name       varchar,
  employees  integer NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (company, city)
);
```

The trick here is that the PK for the company branch is defined on the company identifier and the city identifier **combined**. A PK is always unique in the table.

Assuming that you want population counts and employees in a single query, this would do the trick:

```
SELECT
  company.name AS company,
  branch.name AS branch,
  city.name AS city,
  branch.employees,
  city.population AS city_pop,
  country.population AS country_pop
FROM company
JOIN branch ON branch.company = company.id
JOIN city ON city.id = branch.city
JOIN country ON country.id = city.country
ORDER BY company.name, branch.name;
```

Comment: Thank you a lot!!! I was trying to this with only 3 tables and it was impossible and to be honest it did not make any sense to me. This is very useful for me since I am total newbie to databases. Truly appreciate it!!! take care

Comment: how could I query only NO.of employees that each company have for each country they are present in? I need only 3 columns as result, Country, Company and Employees but only two of them are directly connected via keys? thank you!!

Comment: I'd say you have a new question, just post it as such.